# How to check how frequently a flight is delayed, statistically?

Tags: air-travel, delays, statistics

My mother-in-law's flight from Los Angeles (LAX) to Mactan–Cebu International Airport (CEB) was recently cancelled and then rescheduled for 14 hours later.  She will soon be returning, and I am worried about the CEB to LAX portion of her trip. Is there a way to see how frequently Philippine Airlines delays or cancels these flights?